# Finding element in a binary tree

Tags: search, haskell, tree, find, binary-tree

Assume I have a binary tree:

```
data Bst a = Empty | Node (Bst a) a (Bst a)
```

I have to write a function that searches for a value and returns the number of its children. If there is no node with this value, it returns -1. I was trying to write both BFS and DFS, and I failed with both.

Comment: Please show us the code for your attempts, which will help us pinpoint where things are going wrong.

Comment: Also Haskell uses `Maybe a = Nothing | Just a` to express that an element wasn't found.

Comment: Look at the `Tree` implementation [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#recursive-data-structures). There are functions called `treeInsert` and `treeElem`. They can give an intuition of how to traverse the tree to implement your functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do this. Breath-first search can actually be a bit tricky to implement and this solution (findBFS) has aweful complexity (appending to the list is O(n)) but you'll get the gist.

First I have decided to split out the finding functions to return the tree where the node element matches. That simplifies splitting out the counting function. Also, it is easier to return the number of elements than the number of descendants and return -1 in case not found, so the `numDesc` functions rely on the numElements function.

```
data Tree a = Empty
            | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

numElements :: Tree a -> Int
numElements Empty        = 0
numElements (Node _ l r) = 1 + numElements l + numElements r

findDFS :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
findDFS _ Empty                         = Empty
findDFS x node@(Node y l r) | x == y    = node
                            | otherwise = case findDFS x l of 
                                            node'@(Node _ _ _) -> node'
                                            Empty              -> findDFS x r

findBFS :: Eq a => a -> [Tree a] -> Tree a                                                                
findBFS x []                              = Empty
findBFS x ((Empty):ts)                    = findBFS x ts
findBFS x (node@(Node y _ _):ts) | x == y = node
findBFS x ((Node _ l r):ts)               = findBFS x (ts ++ [l,r])

numDescDFS :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Int
numDescDFS x t = numElements (findDFS x t) - 1

numDescBFS :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Int
numDescBFS x t = numElements (findBFS x [t]) - 1
```

Comment: I can't understand what's going on after `otherwise`... could you explain it more?

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching is your friend. Your `Bst` can either be `Empty` or a `Node`, so at the toplevel, your `search` function will be

```
search Empty = ...
search (Node left x right) = ...
```

Can an `Empty` tree possibly contain the target value? With a `Node` the target value, if present, will be either the node value (`x` above), in the `left` subtree, in the `right` subtree—or perhaps some combination of these.

By “return[ing] the number of its children,” I assume you mean the total number of descendants of the `Bst` rooted at a `Node` whose value is the target, which is an interesting combination of problems. You will want *another* function, say `numChildren`, whose definition uses pattern matching as above. Considerations:

1. How many descendants does an `Empty` tree have?
2. In the `Node` case, `x` doesn’t count because you want *descendants*. If only you had a function to count the number of children in the `left` and `right` subtrees …

Comment: I'd just add that the other magic word he needs is `recursion`. With pattern matching and recursion the assignment it is very easy.